# Pythonic Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to implement a calculation for the Schur Complement of a symmetric matrix. The equation for this value is:

```
M = A - B^T C B
```

Where A, B, C are block components of the matrix

```
S = (A | B^T)
    (B | C )
```

Suppose I have defined numpy arrays for A, B and C:

- A is a 3x3 Matrix
- B is a 3x2 Matrix
- C is a 2x2 matrix

I have performed the operation to obtain S using numpy:

```
 M = A - np.matmul(B.T, np.matmul(C, B))
```

Assuming this is the correct operation, is there a more pythonic way to write this code?

Kind regards!

**Edit:**

Were I using Python 3.5+, then the @ solution suggested would be ideal.

The reason for my question is that, if one was doing a complex set of matrix multiplications, using nested np.matmult() or np.dot() becomes very difficult  to read without defining new variables in each step.

For example, for the equation `M = A^-1 - C^TXC` becomes

```
np.linalg.inv(A) - np.dot(C.T, np.dot(X,C))
```

or

```
 np.linalg.inv(A) - np.matmult(C.T, np.matmult(X,C))
```

The nesting makes it harder to check the operator order is correct, since:

```
np.linalg.inv(A) - np.matmult(C.T, np.matmult(X,C)) != np.linalg.inv(A) - np.matmult(C.T, np.matmult(C,X))
```

(in most cases)

By contrast:

```
np.linalg.inv(A) - C.T @ X @ C
```

Clearly allows the reader to know what is going on in this line of code and to check the operator order.

Comment: ```
M = A - np.matmul(B.T, np.matmul(C, B)) 
```
Seems already Pythonic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the @ shorthand:

M = A - B.T @ C @ B